# git push user id not changing

Tags: git, permissions, config

I have two git ID("theNameBeforeIUsed", "correctName"), 
and I want to change my session.

So I typed,
    
    `$ git config user.email correctmail@email.com
    $ git config --global user.email correctmail@email.com
    $ git config user.name "correctName"
    $ git config --global user.name "correctName"
    $ git push origin master`

But, permission error occurred
    
    `remote: Permission to ~~~.git denied to theNameBeforeIUsed.
    fatal: unable to access '~~~.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`

How can I logout "theNameBeforeIUsed" and login with "correctName"?

Comment: I found answer! The windows saved my git credentials. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238037/git-log-out-user-from-command-line

Answer (score 1):

probably when you clone the repository you use something like this
theNameBeforeIUsed@yourgit.com:proyect.git

so if you change the user when it connect to git it will use theNameBeforeIUsed instead the new user then you need change the file
.git/config

and where it say

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = theNameBeforeIUsed@yourgit.com:project.git
```

use the https version of your project or change there your user, I personally prefer https because is more secure and always ask your user avoiding misunderstandings

Comment: When I type
`git remote show origin`

it says
`Push URL: https://github.com/~~/~~.git`

Comment: check the file anyway

Comment: [core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = false
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 symlinks = false
 ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
 url = https://github.com/~~~/~~~.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[user]
 name = correctName
 email = correctEmail@email.com

Comment: url have no prefix such as username@

Comment: so your git ask for credentials each time that you push or pull isn't it? check if you have a ssh key setted on https://github.com/settings/keys

Comment: It says,
There are no SSH keys with access to your account.
There are no GPG keys with access to your account.

Comment: you don't answer
so your git ask for credentials each time that you push or pull isn't it?

Comment: No, no credential requested when I push or pull.

Comment: then that is the problem, when you have https you always must input the user and the password
what are you using to do pull and push which tool?

Comment: I just use Git Bash
in win7

Comment: I think that is related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186835/git-bash-for-windows-not-prompting-for-password check it for if have the solution to your problem

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: another post that can be helpful is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793680/when-push-in-github-why-git-didnt-ask-me-to-type-username-and-password

Comment: The windows saved credentials. Thank you for your help!